# ¿Como puedo unir dos listas simplemente enlazadas en java?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, método

Es algo muy sencillo pero que me ha dado un poco de dolor de cabeza, soy muy novato. La idea es unir dos listas de modo que:

lista uno = 1, 3, 5

lista dos = 2, 4, 6

El resultado debería ser:

lista tres = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

Ya hice el código para generar las otras dos y el dolor de cabeza va de como unirlas.

Tengo la clase lista

```
    public class listas {

    nodos primero;
    byte tamanio;

    public void Lista() {
        primero = null;
        tamanio = 0;
    }

    public boolean esVacia() {
        return primero == null;
    }

    public int getTamanio() {
        return tamanio;
    }

    public void agregarAlFinal(int dato){
        nodos nuevo = new nodos();        
        nuevo.setDato(dato);
        if (esVacia()) {         
            primero = nuevo;   
        } else{
            nodos aux = primero;
            while(aux.getSiguiente() != null){
                aux = aux.getSiguiente();
            }
            aux.setSiguiente(nuevo);
        }
        tamanio++;
    }


    public void MostrarLista(){
        if (!esVacia()) {
            nodos aux = primero;            
            while(aux != null){
                System.out.print(" [ " + aux.getDato() + " ] ");
                aux = aux.getSiguiente();
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }       
    }     
}
```

Y la clase Nodos

```
public class nodos {

    int dato, dato2;
    nodos siguiente;

    public void Nodo(){
        this.dato = 0;
        this.siguiente = null;
    }

    public int getDato() {
        return dato;
    }

    public void setDato(int dato) {
        this.dato = dato;
    }

    public void setDato(int dato, int dato2){
        this.dato = dato;
        this.dato2 = dato2;
    }

    public int getDato2() {
        return dato2;
    }

    public void setDato2(int dato2) {
        this.dato2 = dato2;
    }

    public nodos getSiguiente() {
        return siguiente;
    }

    public void setSiguiente(nodos siguiente) {
        this.siguiente = siguiente;
    }  
}
```

Y la clase principal.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        listas lista_est = new listas();
        listas lista_prg = new listas();
//        listatr3s lista_tr3s = new listatr3s();

        int est = 0, prg = 0, opc = 0;

        do{
            System.out.print("\n1. Insertar numero de estudiantes." + 
                    "\n" + "2. Insertar número de preguntas." +
                    "\n" + "3. Mostrar tamaño de listas vigentes." + 
                    "\n" + "4. Juntar las dos listas." + 
                    "\n" + "5. Darle <play> a la asignación." +
                    "\n" + "6. Salir. \n");

            System.out.print("\nOpción: ");
            opc = leer.nextByte();

            switch(opc){
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("Ingrese el número de estudiantes: ");
                    est = leer.nextByte();
                    for (byte i = 1; i <= est; i++) {
                        lista_est.agregarAlFinal(i);
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.print("Ingrese el número de preguntas: ");
                    byte cant2 = leer.nextByte();
                    for (byte i = 0; i < cant2; i++) {
                        prg = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(cant2-1)+1);
                        lista_prg.agregarAlFinal(prg);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.print("Listado estudiantes: "); lista_est.MostrarLista();
                    System.out.print("Listado preguntas: "); lista_prg.MostrarLista();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.print("Se agrega a la tercera lista.");
//                    lista_tr3s.agregarAlFinal(lista_est, lista_prg);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Listado con la asignación: ");
//                    lista_tr3s.Mostrar3Lista();
                    break;            
            }            
        }while(opc != 6);       
    }
```

Eso me funciona perfectamente bien para generar las listas, lo que tengo entendido es que tengo que hacer otra clase para generar un TERCERA lista. Lo que se me hace dificil es realizar el código para unir las dos listas creadas.

Comment: No podemos darte el código porque la idea es que tú mismo lo hagas o por lo menos lo intentes, pero creo que puedo darte unas pautas para hacerlo, tomando en cuenta que la lista que quieres crear al final en una lista ordenada, deberías crear un método en la clase listas que te retorne el nodo que debe ser el anterior al nuevo elemento a agregar es decir el nodo cuyo dato es el menor más cercano al nuevo a agregar, y a partir de ahí crear un método agregar y no debería ser demasiado complicado hacer la unión de las listas y que la retorne ordenada.

Comment: Hola Edward, este problema es simple, pero no tan trivial, has intentado algo? No podemos darte la solución así tal cual, va en contra de las normas del sitio, según se lee en [ask].

Comment: Si claro que lo he intentado, se me ha ocurrido recorrer las dos listas pero la verdad es que quedo en blanco y lo que llevo ahora no funciona